# PDO Query (insert and select) doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to insert data into my database and with the same prepared statement I'd like to select the id of the new inserted row.

Therefore I'm using the following code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question) VALUES (:question1), (:question2); SELECT @@IDENTITY  as 'currentID';");

if ($stmt -> execute(array(":question1" => $_POST["question1"], ":question2" => $_POST["question2"]))) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $row["currentID"]; //doesn't output anything
    echo "hey"; //gets outputted
}
```

This works fine using phpMyAdmin and entering the code there. But using my PHP script, it inserts the data but it doesn't return the currentID.
But I don't get any error.

Exactly the same if I try to select anything else.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: `VALUES (:question1), (:question2);` < it's probably the semi-colon here, ending the statement. TBH, I've never used INSERT/SELECT, so this is purely a guess on my part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- as I said, I don't get any error message. And the insert-select command is different to what I'm looking for. And without the semicolon it doesn't work at all and I get an error message.

Comment: You should ask your connection for the last insert ID (`$id = $pdo->lastInsertID()`), and then build a select query from that result. Or you could just do `echo $id` to see what that ID was.

Comment: @Chris1 what database you are using? @@identity doesn't seem very mysql.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's a mysql database and @@identity did work using phpMyAdmin. But way more elegant and easier is using `lastInsertId()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question1, question2) VALUES (:question1), (:question2)");

if ($stmt -> execute(array(":question1" => $_POST["question1"], ":question2" => $_POST["question2"]))) {
    $id = $pdo->lastInsertID();
    echo $id;
}
```

From there, you can go on to build a select (`SELECT * from question where id = $id` or whatever else you want to do

Comment: You don't need this `SELECT @@IDENTITY  as 'currentID';` if u gonna use last insert id

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `lastInsertID()`, works great.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike database console, in PHP you are running queries against a database **one by one**.
So you are supposed to do:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question) VALUES (:question1), (:question2)");
$stmt -> execute(array(":question1" => $_POST["question1"], ":question2" => $_POST["question2"]));

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT @@IDENTITY  as 'currentID'");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $row["currentID"];
```

and you should be doing exactly the same trying to select anything else.